# Getting error when trying to send my r and png files to git hub repository

Tags: github

I modified the above steps a bit , but, I am still getting the error
Here are the new steps:
1. copied all my r codes and .png files into the “Data_Analysis_Project_2” folder on my system

In the terminal:

```
cd ~/ Data_Analysis_Project_2
git init
git remote add origin
https://github.com/pruthvivenkata/Data_Analysis_Project_2.git
git add
git commit -m "committed"
git push origin master
```

After step 7, I am getting the following error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/pruthvivenkata/Data_Analysis_Project_2.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do

hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing

hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes

hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: What happened when you did what the error message you quote suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that some changes were made to your Github repository that aren't currently reflected in your local repo. In order to avoid a conflict, you have to `git pull` the remote changes into your local repository before attempting to push your new changes to the remote repo.

Comment: can you specify the the command that I need to type to do the git pull?. Is it

Comment: I typed git pull origin master, But I am not sure if its right

Comment: Problem solved . I typed

Comment: git pull --rebase origin master

Comment: and then "git push origin master"